# Blazor server app: InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) doesnt change table

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to implement dynamic change on data in table. As I was told, I need to use HubConnection which works fine. Then I try to use  InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); which should update me a content of table.

```cs
@page "/online-chat"

@foreach (var post in PostsList)
{
    <p>@post.AuthorName | @post.MessageText</p>
}

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
@using StudujFriUniza.Data;
@using StudujFriUniza.Services;
@inject PostsService postsService;
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
    List<Post> PostsList = new List<Post>();
    private HubConnection? hubConnection;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        PostsList = await postsService.GetAllPosts();

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri("/postsHub"))
            .Build();

        //method is invoked
        hubConnection.On<List<Post>>("RefreshPosts", posts =>
            {
                PostsList = posts; //posts are updated
                InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); //doesnt change UI
            });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

Howewer, table stays same.

Using StateHasChanged() produces exception that tells:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.' `

Comment: If `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` is running without an exception then it's queueing a render.  If `PostList` contains a updated list, then the render will render that list.  So at the moment I'm left thinking there's something you're not telling us that is important.  Add a simple timestamp field to the component.  Update it in the callback, show it on the page and log it to the console.

Comment: you could try using this syntax for `hubConnection.On<List<Post>>("RefreshPosts", (posts) =>
{
    PostsList = posts; 
    InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    });
});`

Comment: Adding `@rendermode InteractiveServer` seems to fix my issue.